# How to fix these form theming problems in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have multiple questions about forms

**First question, how to wrap an input with a div (with classes) in the form builder?**

So I want to wrap this submit input :

```
->add('Submit', 'submit', array(
    'attr' =>  array(
        'class' => 'btn btn-success'
    ),
))
```

To get this result :

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
</div>
```

**Second question, how to set a template to a form via the form builder?**

Is there a method for this like in my wrong example? Or not?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setTemplate('::vertical-form.html.twig')
        ->add(...)
}
```

**Last question, how to add a class to the form element in a custom form template?**

I grab this piece of code from **form_div_layout.html.twig** and I add the class (9th line) to the form element. But it doesn't work, I can't see the  element in my view!

```
{% block form_start %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set method = method|upper %}
        {% if method in ["GET", "POST"] %}
            {% set form_method = method %}
        {% else %}
            {% set form_method = "POST" %}
        {% endif %}
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="{{ form.vars.name }}" method="{{ form_method|lower }}" action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
        {% if form_method != method %}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_start %}
```

In my views, I've only that piece of code to render the form:

```
{% form_theme form '::custom-form.html.twig' %}
{{ form(form_name) }}
```

Maybe should I copy all **form_div_layout.html.twig** file to another template and tweak what I need?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. In my opinion in this case You should create submit button manually in a template (not by form class)
2. I don't know solution which looks like this.
3. You should copy all file content.
   Read this:
   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll create a form theme for each purpose.